# How to use OSMDROID?

Tags: android, openstreetmap, libraries, osmdroid

I'm using OSMDROID libraries for the offline map. I added these libraries to the Project:

1. `"osmdroid-android-3.0.10.jar"`,
2. `"osmdroid-android-3.0.10-javadoc.jar"` and
3. `"slf4j-android-1.5.8.jar"`

I have downloaded the requirements map and now, what should I do to this map? I'm trying to run the application but errors happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly you might have not added you library to your project correctly. I recommend you to follow this article:
http://www.haakseth.com/?p=30

Answer (score 1):

Simply adding the libraries files to your project won't work. You have to build the path also and then configure the build path and add source and javadoc location to your added files.

Configure your build path for osmdroid-android-3.0.10.jar. Please follow the steps given here:

1. Right click on your added library files select Build Path --> Configure Build Path.
2. Select library tab
3. Explore osmdroid-android-3.0.10.jar and select source attachment
4. Click Edit Button on the right side and select Workspace Location in the pop-up screen and locate your file where you saved or copied the osmdroid-android-3.0.10.jar file.

Similarly Select Javadoc Location and click on Edit button. In the pop-up screen select Javadoc in Archive and then select Workspace file. Now browse the Archive path where your javadoc file is located. Finally browse the Path within archive, select the file there and click ok. You are done with adding the library files properly.

Comment: Configure the Build Path in first step is not required always. I tried with osmdroid-android-4.2.jar and it worked fine. 

Simply place your jar files into lib folder and select Build Path